# Asp.net MVC 2 on Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

Anybody have asp.net mvc 2 running with visual studio 2010?

Is it as easy as referencing the output of the mvc 2 source code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Visual Studio 2010 Beta 2 will include asp.net MVC 2 Preview 2. Scott Gu confirmed this in Manchester/London, England last month.

Also Preview 1 is supported in 2010 - I've got it installed, Phil Haack had a release (it's 1.0; but says 1.1 to get it to work in 2010. see here:
http://aspnet.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=28527

Roll on 2010!

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET MVC 2 (Preview 1) is not supported in VS 2010 Beta 1.  Beta 2 will include it (not sure which Preview).